# Delete references to an object in python if incorrectly initialized?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, object, garbage-collection

I am trying to write a brief G-code compiler that is low weight for a very specific application, I am trying to remove incorrectly made objects gracefully as well as free the memory allocation to that object.

I currently have been playing around and trying to figure out when an object falls out of scope but I still cannot find the reason that this test object I am using will not be flagged by GC until the script is shutting down.

Is it even necessary or am I brutally over thinking this problem?
Thanks!

```
'''
Rectangle object for use in drawing and holding positions for later use when
parsing G-Code Files
'''

from collections import namedtuple

Point = namedtuple('Point', ['x_pos', 'y_pos'])

obj_ref = []

class Rectangle(object):
    '''
    Object which takes four tuples of (X_pos, Y_pos) format

    a_vert shall be set as origin point for the object

    C _ D
    |   |
    A _ B  format
    '''

    def __init__(self, a_vert, b_vert, c_vert, d_vert):
        # Asterisk (*) means *args in this case
        self.a_vert = Point(*a_vert)
        self.b_vert = Point(*b_vert)
        self.c_vert = Point(*c_vert)
        self.d_vert = Point(*d_vert)

        # Verification for object creation
        # First IF verifies points that should be the same
        if(self.a_vert.y_pos == self.b_vert.y_pos and
           self.a_vert.x_pos == self.c_vert.x_pos and
           self.b_vert.x_pos == self.d_vert.x_pos and
           self.c_vert.y_pos == self.d_vert.y_pos):
            # Second IF verifies points that cannot be the same
            if(self.a_vert.y_pos != self.c_vert.y_pos and
               self.b_vert.y_pos != self.d_vert.y_pos):
                global obj_ref   # List of properly made objects
                obj_ref.append(id(self))
        else:
            raise Exception()  # TODO: Custom Vertex Exception

    def set_Rec(self, a_vert, b_vert, c_vert, d_vert):
        self.a_vert = Point(*a_vert)
        self.b_vert = Point(*b_vert)
        self.c_vert = Point(*c_vert)
        self.d_vert = Point(*d_vert)

    def get_Rec(self):
        return (self.a_vert, self.b_vert, self.c_vert, self.d_vert)

    def __del__(self):  # Removes from obj_ref to allow for GC collection
        global obj_ref
        obj_ref.remove(id(self))
        print("Object Deleted: %s" % id(self))


# Testing named tuple code for Rectangle Instances
a = (1, 2)
b = (4, 2)
c = (1, 4)
d = (4, 4)
e = (1, 8)
f = (4, 8)
test = Rectangle(a, b, c, d)

print(test.a_vert)
test.set_Rec(a, b, e, f)
print(test.c_vert)
print(test.get_Rec())
```

Comment: Verify the objects *before* you assign them to attributes.

Comment: That honestly makes a lot more sense. I shall try that immediately. Thanks @Barmar